# Find a unit vector from the direction (3, -1, 4) to (1, 3, 5)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

SO this is my question

Find a unit vector in the direction from

$\begin{bmatrix}3 \\-1 \\4\end{bmatrix}$$ to $$\begin{bmatrix}1 \\3 \\5\end{bmatrix}$

My solution:

I used the distance formula first.

$D$ $=$ $\sqrt{(1-3)^2 + (3+1)^2 + (5-4)^2} = \sqrt{21}$

Then for the unit vector I'm confused because wouldn't you take the distance and multiply it by the original equation?

Comment: You need to find the vector between the two points you are given, and apply an appropriate scale factor to that.

Comment: What would be the formula for that?

Comment: a unit vector has the form $\frac{\vec{a}}{|\vec{a}|}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given two points $p_1, p_2$ the vector $p_2-p_1$ is in the direction of $p_1p_2$.

A unit vector in the same direction of a given (nonzero) vector can be obtained by scaling down the given vector (i.e. each component) by the magnitude of the vector.

Can you solve it now?

Comment: So first i would do p2 - p1, then i don't get the part about can be obtained by scaling down the given  vector?

Comment: Yes. Let $v = p_2 - p_1$. Now $||v||$, the magnitude of $v$ is essentially what you have calculated: $\sqrt{21}$. In general, $||v|| = \sqrt{\sum_{i = 1}^n v_i^2 }$, where $v$ is $n$ dimensional.

Comment: so it would be pretty much $(p2-p1)/\sqrt(21)$?

Comment: In this case, yes. In general, $(p_2 - p_1) / d(p_1, p_2)$.